# UITableView Separator Style "Single Line Etched" not working properly

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableView in my code and am trying to get the Single Line Etched style working, where it has the 1px white drop shadow at the bottom. Instead, I'm getting a sort of negative gray shadow at the top when I enable it. Neither programmatic nor IB implementation is yielding the 1 px drop shadow. Here's a link to a screenshot of what it looks like with the negative gray shadow:

[image: http://imgur.com/8Ikj2]

TL;DR: I'd like the Single Line Etched style to give me a 1px white drop shadow instead of the 1px gray inner shadow it gives me now at the top.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while, but the problem here lay in the iPhone Simulator itself. As soon as I launched the app on an actual iOS device, everything worked fine and the white drop shadow was there. Regardless, thank you for the advice, BPratt–I'm sure that'll come into use for another situation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that a grouped table repects the etched option, but a very quick work around is to create an image that has the exact look that you want and set the background image of the table cell to this image.  Set the background image in the same method that you are setting up the rest of the data for each cell.  Finally set the line style to "none" in IB.