# Set TableView SeperatorStyle to SingleLineEtched dont work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i tied to set the Seperator Style of my `UITableView` to `SingleLineEtched`, but it didn´t work. First i tried to set it in my Interface Builder, as you can see i set the Table Style to "Grouped":

[image]

But then my `TableView` don't show any seperate Lines..nothing....
So i tried it programmatically with:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

but that also don´t work.
Some Ideas what i´m doing wrong?

Comment: What is your background colour? White?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652019/uitableview-separator-style-single-line-etched-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

try using it in device, as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652019/uitableview-separator-style-single-line-etched-not-working-properly) the problem here lay in the iPhone Simulator itself

Comment: Thanks, but i only use my device, so that can not be the Problem.